# Xmlstarlet - copy value of one attribute to another, if it exists in an element

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have just learned about xmlstarlet, but unfortunately I have a really hard time with XML, so I hope I'll get some help with this ...

Say, I have this XML file, `test.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
  <g id="layer3" inkscape:label="hello">
    <circle id="circ2" inkscape:label="there"/>
    <rect id="rect2" inkscape:label="world"/>
  </g>
  <g id="layer4">
    <circle id="circ3" inkscape:label="more"/>
  </g>
</objects>
```

So what I want to do is: for each node where `inkscape:label` attribute exists, copy value of the `inkscape:label` attribute to the `id` attribute; so the expected output from the above would be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
  <g id="hello" inkscape:label="hello">
    <circle id="there" inkscape:label="there"/>
    <rect id="world" inkscape:label="world"/>
  </g>
  <g id="layer4">
    <circle id="more" inkscape:label="more"/>
  </g>
</objects>
```

How can I do this with xmlstarlet?

---

Apparently I can replace all id attributes with a fixed value by using expression `string("TEST")` like this:

```
$  xmlstarlet edit -N inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" --update '//*/@id' --expr 'string("TEST")'
test.xml
test.xml:3.40: Namespace prefix inkscape for label on g is not defined
  <g id="layer3" inkscape:label="hello">
                                       ^
test.xml:4.46: Namespace prefix inkscape for label on circle is not defined
    <circle id="circ2" inkscape:label="there"/>
                                             ^
test.xml:5.44: Namespace prefix inkscape for label on rect is not defined
    <rect id="rect2" inkscape:label="world"/>
                                           ^
test.xml:8.45: Namespace prefix inkscape for label on circle is not defined
    <circle id="circ3" inkscape:label="more"/>
                                            ^
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
  <g id="TEST" inkscape:label="hello">
    <circle id="TEST" inkscape:label="there"/>
    <rect id="TEST" inkscape:label="world"/>
  </g>
  <g id="TEST">
    <circle id="TEST" inkscape:label="more"/>
  </g>
</objects>
```

... and I can "reinsert" the value of the attribute id with expression `string(../@id)` like this (so I basically get same output as input):

```
$ xmlstarlet edit -N inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" --update '//*/@id' --expr 'string(../@id)' test.xml
test.xml:3.40: Namespace prefix inkscape for label on g is not defined
  <g id="layer3" inkscape:label="hello">
                                       ^
test.xml:4.46: Namespace prefix inkscape for label on circle is not defined
    <circle id="circ2" inkscape:label="there"/>
                                             ^
test.xml:5.44: Namespace prefix inkscape for label on rect is not defined
    <rect id="rect2" inkscape:label="world"/>
                                           ^
test.xml:8.45: Namespace prefix inkscape for label on circle is not defined
    <circle id="circ3" inkscape:label="more"/>
                                            ^
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
  <g id="layer3" inkscape:label="hello">
    <circle id="circ2" inkscape:label="there"/>
    <rect id="rect2" inkscape:label="world"/>
  </g>
  <g id="layer4">
    <circle id="circ3" inkscape:label="more"/>
  </g>
</objects>
```

... but I cannot use the same trick (expression `string(../@inkscape:label)` - or `string(../@*[local-name()='label'])` as per [How does local-name find attributes in an xml node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455023/how-does-local-name-find-attributes-in-an-xml-node)) to read from attribute `inkscape:label` - and I cannot really tell whether that is because of the "Namespace prefix" .. "not defined" message:

```
$ xmlstarlet edit -N inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" --update '//*/@id' --expr 'string(../@inkscape:label)' test.xml
test.xml:3.40: Namespace prefix inkscape for label on g is not defined
  <g id="layer3" inkscape:label="hello">
                                       ^
test.xml:4.46: Namespace prefix inkscape for label on circle is not defined
    <circle id="circ2" inkscape:label="there"/>
                                             ^
test.xml:5.44: Namespace prefix inkscape for label on rect is not defined
    <rect id="rect2" inkscape:label="world"/>
                                           ^
test.xml:8.45: Namespace prefix inkscape for label on circle is not defined
    <circle id="circ3" inkscape:label="more"/>
                                            ^
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
  <g id="" inkscape:label="hello">
    <circle id="" inkscape:label="there"/>
    <rect id="" inkscape:label="world"/>
  </g>
  <g id="">
    <circle id="" inkscape:label="more"/>
  </g>
</objects>
```

And via [get attribute value using xmlstarlet or xmllint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595262/get-attribute-value-using-xmlstarlet-or-xmllint) ; I can confirm I can target the id attribute with:

```
xmlstarlet select -N inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" --template --value-of '//*/@id' test.xml
```

... but the corresponding command for the inkscape:label returns nothing:

```
xmlstarlet select -N inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" --template --value-of '//*/@inkscape:label' test.xml
```

It's probably that namespace thing, but I don't understand how can I ignore the namespace, and just relate to the attribute names in the document as they are ...

---

EDIT: finally solved the issue here with Python 3:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097949/elementtree-findall-to-recursively-select-all-child-elements
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372604/python-elementtree-parsing-unbound-prefix-error
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352840/parsing-broken-xml-with-lxml-etree-iterparse
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813876/how-do-i-get-pythons-elementtree-to-pretty-print-to-an-xml-file

import sys
import lxml
import lxml.etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def proc_node(node):
  target_label = 'inkscape:label' # file without namespace, like `test.xml` here
  #target_label = '{http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape}label' # file with namespace (like proper Inkscape .svg)
  if target_label in node.attrib:
    node.attrib['id'] = node.attrib[target_label]
  for childel in node.getchildren():
    proc_node(childel)


parser1 = lxml.etree.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8", recover=True)
tree1 = ET.parse('test.xml', parser1)
ET.indent(tree1, space="  ", level=0)
proc_node(tree1.getroot())
print(lxml.etree.tostring(tree1.getroot(), xml_declaration=True, pretty_print=True, encoding='UTF-8').decode('utf-8'))
```

... if I call this `xmlproc.py`, then the result is:

```
$ python3 xmlproc.py
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<objects>
  <g id="hello" inkscape:label="hello">
    <circle id="there" inkscape:label="there"/>
    <rect id="world" inkscape:label="world"/>
  </g>
  <g id="layer4">
    <circle id="more" inkscape:label="more"/>
  </g>
</objects>
```

... which is exactly what I wanted.

So to specify in the spirit of how the question is postulated - how do I achieve this with xmlstarlet?

Comment: Are you sure `test.xml` really looks like your sample xml in the question? That sample doesn't have a namespace declaration for `inkspace` and ET would return an "unbound prefix" error.

Comment: Thanks @JackFleeting - indeed, my actual file is an `inkspace` one, but since I forgot everything about XML (and namespaces) that I might have known in the past, I got surprised to see that doing a "minimal example" would not work in general, due to XML namespace prefixes. So the Python code shows how to handle that in either case - and I am wondering if, with special switches, `xmlstarlet` can be made to do the same (i.e. process both a minimal XML file with no namespace info apart from attribute prefix, and a "real" "properly namespaced" XML file)

Answer (score 2):

> in the spirit of how the question is postulated - how do I achieve this with xmlstarlet?

The input file doesn't define the `inkscape` namespace which causes
the XML parser ([libxml2](/questions/tagged/libxml2)) to issue messages and parse the
`inkscape:label` nodes as attributes belonging to the null namespace.
Recall that `:` (colon) in component names is [tolerated](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-name)
but [unrecommended](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-xml-names-20091208#dt-nwf), and the default namespace
[doesn't](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-xml-names-20091208#uniqAttrs) apply to attribute names.

To produce the desired output you can say,

```sh
xmlstarlet -q edit \
  -u '//*[@*[local-name()="inkscape:label"][namespace-uri()=""]]/@id' \
  -x 'string(../@*[local-name()="inkscape:label"][namespace-uri()=""])' \
file.xml
```

where

- the global [`-q`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139669232) option suppresses
  messages from the parser about the missing namespace definition
- [`local-name()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#function-local-name)
  and [`namespace-uri()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#function-namespace-uri)
  are used as a workaround in the special case where an unprefixed
  name contains a `:` (colon), because `@inkscape:label` would cause
  the parser to look for the non-existing `inkscape` namespace

---

Since `inkscape` is probably a namespace prefix in most contexts here
are 2 alternative methods. You can have `xmlstarlet` add a missing
namespace node by modifying the input using either `edit`,

```sh
xmlstarlet -q edit \
  -s '*' -t attr -n 'xmlns:inkscape' -v 'http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape' \
file.xml |
xmlstarlet edit -u '//*[@inkscape:label]/@id' -x 'string(../@inkscape:label)'
```

or a [`pyx`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139550832) `… | sed … | depyx -` pipeline,

```sh
xmlstarlet -q pyx file.xml |
sed '1a\
Axmlns:inkscape http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape' |
xmlstarlet depyx - |
xmlstarlet edit -u '//*[@inkscape:label]/@id' -x 'string(../@inkscape:label)'
```

The root element of the output XML will contain the `inkscape` namespace
node. To produce the desired output (less the XML declaration) the
namespace node can be deleted by appending
`| xmlstarlet pyx - | sed '/^Axmlns:inkscape /d' | xmlstarlet depyx -`
to the previous command. (`xmlstarlet edit` cannot delete namespace nodes.)

Converting XML to [PYX](https://www.xml.com/pub/2000/03/15/feature/index.html)
notation during processing is occasionally useful for simple queries or
editing of non-complex data, but XPath access is out.
Beware that `xmlstarlet`'s `pyx` and `depyx` commands **do not guarantee**
an accurate roundtrip. `depyx`, for example, outputs non-collapsed empty
elements (such as `<void></void>`) so an extra pass through `xmlstarlet format`
is sometimes in order.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with `xmllint` in 3 steps:

1. get label values
2. Build XPath to set @id values
3. execute XPath expression

```bash
    # Step 1 - get label values into an array for elements containing both attributes
    labels=( $(printf '%s\n' 'setrootns' 'cat //*[@inkscape:label and @id]/@inkscape:label' | xmllint --shell tmp.xml | sed -rne '/inkscape:label/ s/inkscape:label="(.*)"/\1/p' ) )

    # Step 2 - build xpath
    xpath=( 'setrootns' )
    for i in "${!labels[@]}"; do
        # get current element name ;-)
        xpath[${#xpath[@]}]="xpath name((//*[@inkscape:label and @id])[$i+1])"
        xpath[${#xpath[@]}]="cd (//*[@inkscape:label and @id])[$i+1]/@id"
        xpath[${#xpath[@]}]="set ${labels[$i]}"
    done
    xpath[${#xpath[@]}]='save'
    xpath[${#xpath[@]}]='bye'

    #Step 3 - execute Xpath
    printf "%s\n" "${xpath[@]}" | xmllint --shell tmp.xml
```

Most significant XPath expression is the one to find elements having both attributes where nodeset index is the  `labels` array index + 1

```
(//*[@inkscape:label and @id])[$i+1]
```

Script output

```
/ > setrootns
/ > xpath name((//*[@inkscape:label and @id])[0+1])
Object is a string : g
/ > cd (//*[@inkscape:label and @id])[0+1]/@id
id > set hello
id > xpath name((//*[@inkscape:label and @id])[1+1])
Object is a string : circle
id > cd (//*[@inkscape:label and @id])[1+1]/@id
id > set there
id > xpath name((//*[@inkscape:label and @id])[2+1])
Object is a string : rect
id > cd (//*[@inkscape:label and @id])[2+1]/@id
id > set world
id > xpath name((//*[@inkscape:label and @id])[3+1])
Object is a string : circle
id > cd (//*[@inkscape:label and @id])[3+1]/@id
id > set more
id > save
id > bye
```