# How to flatten XML with xmlstarlet?

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have an XML file that I'd like to flatten.

**input.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
  <item id="item1">
    <oldproperty oldname="mykey" oldvalue="keyname1"/>
    <oldproperty oldname="myval" oldvalue="value1"/>
  </item>
  <item id="item2">
    <oldproperty oldname="mykey" oldvalue="keyname2"/>
    <oldproperty oldname="myval" oldvalue="value2"/>
  </item>
  <item id="item3">
    <oldproperty oldname="mykey" oldvalue="keyname3"/>
    <oldproperty oldname="myval" oldvalue="value3"/>
  </item>
</items>
```

**Desired output:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
  <item id="item1" newkey="keyname1" newvalue="value1"/>
  <item id="item2" newkey="keyname2" newvalue="value2"/>
  <item id="item3" newkey="keyname3" newvalue="value3"/>
</items>
```

**QUESTION:** How can I do that with `xmlstarlet`?

Comment: Probably not possible in a single command. [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74062383/2834978) to a similar question but using `xmllint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired output can be produced by `xmlstarlet edit`:

```sh
xmlstarlet edit \
  -s '*/*' -t attr -n newkey -v '' \
  -u '$prev' -x 'string(../oldproperty[@oldname="mykey"]/@oldvalue)' \
  -s '*/*' -t attr -n newvalue -v '' \
  -u '$prev' -x 'string(../oldproperty[@oldname="myval"]/@oldvalue)' \
  -d '*/*/oldproperty' \
file.xml
```

- unlike `-s (--subnode)`'s `-v (--value)` the `-x (--expr)` clause
  of the `-u (--update)` option takes an XPath argument, hence the
  two-step approach
- the `$prev` variable refers to the node(s) created by the most recent
  `-s`, `-i`, or `-a` option which all define or redefine it (see
  [`xmlstarlet.txt`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet.txt)
  for examples of `$prev`)
- `*/*` may be replaced with `items/item`

or  `xmlstarlet select`:

```sh
xmlstarlet select --xml-decl -E 'UTF-8' --indent -t \
  -e '{name(*)}' \
    -m '*/*' \
      -e '{name()}' \
        -a 'id'       -v '@id' -b \
        -a 'newkey'   -v '*[@oldname="mykey"]/@oldvalue' -b \
        -a 'newvalue' -v '*[@oldname="myval"]/@oldvalue' \
file.xml
```

- `-e (--elem)` emits an element (here using an XSLT
  [*attribute value template*](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#dt-attribute-value-template))
- `-a (--attr)` emits an attribute, `-v (--value-of)` takes
  an XPath argument
- `*[@oldname="…"]` may be replaced with `oldproperty[@oldname="…"]`
- `*/*` may be replaced with `items/item`

(Assuming POSIX shell syntax.)